# PHPthumb fopen - php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, linux, centos

I am getting error on `centOS` server, it is working fine on `XAMPP` localhost.

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service notKnown CURL available but return no data.

CentOS Linux 7.1.1503

Comment: please add your php code

Comment: cant add `php` code in it , because PHPthumb library have a lot of code in it.